# How to call .NET Framework methods in their own process from .NET 7?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, reflection.emit

I'm working on a .NET 7 WPF application that relies on a .NET Framework (4.8.1) library that uses Reflection.Emit (with `AssemblyBuilder.Save`). When I call methods from that library from my application, it throws an exception complaining that it can't find the Reflection.Emit methods. Is there a way to start the .NET Framework methods in their own process, so they can access the required methods?

Comment: According to [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-1-0): _if you want to share code between .NET Framework and any other .NET implementation, such as .NET Core, your library should target .NET Standard 2.0._

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid not sure that this will help in this case due to `Reflection.Emit`.

Comment: In short - no. In long - probably yes, but arguably the time better spend would be rewriting the library.

Comment: You can't start a method in a process, but you could write a .NET Framework application that uses the library as normal, and communicate with that using some form of IPC. Per Guru Stron though, you should first strongly consider finding an alternative for the library instead, as this certainly doesn't make things any easier.

Comment: @GuruStron I'll wait for .NET Core to add ``AssemblyBuilder.Save``, but until then I won't upgrade the library [which i wrote]. Alternatives such as ``Lokad.ILPack`` are too buggy and don't support essential features such as setting an assembly entry point.

Comment: BTW why do you need to generate assembly at runtime? TBH with source generators introduction it is much more rarely a correct approach. As for process options  - the problem here that you will need to fire up a full .NET Framework app in a separate process and somehow manage inter-process communication.

Comment: @GuruStron I'm writing a compiler. I want to be able to save the compiled programs to the disk.